# Ensure Y height of objects in an array is a function of image size in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have a json that contains data about a set of objects (and accompanying images), including their weight.  I am trying to load a subset of those objects into an array, and then display images of the objects in proportion to their weight. I'm using the `objectRadius` variable to hold that proportion.

That part more or less works. However, I'm having trouble setting the Y position of the objects based on their `objectRadius`. Eventually I'm going to stack them, but for now I just want to load them so that the top of each image is aligned with the top of the canvas.

I think that setting the Y position to the `objectRadius` should do that (or, if I'm misunderstanding exactly how the images are positioned, the center of the image will be aligned with the top of the canvas - that's also fine for now).

Unfortunately, with my current code the images are loading at what appear to be random Y positions.  I can hard code a number into the

`itemObject = new Block(width / 2, objectRadius, objectRadius, objectRadius, objectImage, parseFloat(objectWeight), objectDescription);`

line, but any attempt to use a variable for the Y position creates unexpected behavior.  I would love suggestions for what I am sure is the obvious thing I am overlooking.

thank you!

```js
//this is the variable for the state machine
let state = "title";
//this is the variable for the target weight
let targetWeight = 50;
//you subtract each object from the target weight to build the collection, but still need the original number to calculate the size of the object
let originalTargetWeight = targetWeight

//variable for the blocks
let blocks = [];

//this is the shaved down json to hold the objects that have been chosen to represent the weight
let objectHolder = [];


function preload(){
  metDataHolder = [
{
    
    "Object_ID": "453451",
    "Object_Name": "Coin",
    "weight_kg": "0.012927"
},
{
    "Object_ID": "444660",
    "Object_Name": "Turban ornament",
    "weight_kg": "0.048761"
},
{
    "Object_ID": "242191",
    "Object_Name": "Statue fragment",
    "weight_kg": "0.1"
},
{
    "Object_ID": "203797",
    "Object_Name": "Candlestand",
    "weight_kg": "6.8"
},
{
    "Object_Number": "2016.375",
    "Object_ID": "714900",
    "weight_kg": "12.1"
},
{
    "Object_ID": "23198",
    "Object_Name": "Armor",
    "weight_kg": "25.4"
}
  ]
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 800);

}


function draw() {
  background(0);

  if (state == "title") {
    fill("#0f82af");
    textSize(80);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text("Title", width / 2, height / 2);
  } else if (state == "animation") {

    //work through the blocks (assuming there is something in them)
    if (blocks.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        //and display them
        blocks[i].show();
        //move all of the other objects up
      }
    
    }



  } else {
    fill(0);
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  // itemImage = loadImage('images/10025.jpg');
  // let itemObject = new Block(100, 100, 100, 100, itemImage);
  // blocks.push(itemObject);


  while (targetWeight > 1) {
    //pick an object at random
    randoPlace = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(metDataHolder).length);
    //if the weight of that item is below targetWeight
    if (metDataHolder[randoPlace].weight_kg <targetWeight) {
      //subtract the object's weight from the targetweight
      targetWeight = targetWeight - metDataHolder[randoPlace].weight_kg;
      //load the image on the fly
      imagePath = "images/" + metDataHolder[randoPlace].Object_ID + ".jpg";
      objectImage = loadImage(imagePath);
      //get the weight of the object
      objectWeight = metDataHolder[randoPlace].weight_kg;
      console.log("object weight = " + objectWeight);
      objectDescription = metDataHolder[randoPlace].Object_Name;
      //get the placement point
      //the object will take up a portion of that space in proportion to its weight
      objectRadius = (height * (objectWeight/originalTargetWeight));


      //add this object to objectHolder
      thisObject = {"description":objectDescription, "weight":targetWeight, "radius":objectRadius, "imagePath":objectImage};

      objectHolder.push(thisObject);


      //create a block and place it horizontally in the middle, height somewhere random
      //let itemObject = new Block(width / 2, getRndInteger(50, height - 50), objectRadius, objectRadius, objectImage, parseFloat(objectWeight), objectDescription);
      itemObject = new Block(width / 2, objectRadius, objectRadius, objectRadius, objectImage, parseFloat(objectWeight), objectDescription);
      // put the block in the blocks array (or whatever it is called)
      blocks.push(itemObject);
    }
  }

  //function to sort objects by weight (heavy first)
  function blockReorder( a, b ) {
    if ( a.weight < b.weight ){
      return 1;
    }
    if ( a.weight > b.weight ){
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  blocks.sort( blockReorder );





  //console.log(objectHolder);
  console.log(blocks);
  state = "animation";


}

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
}

class Block {
  //create the blocks
  constructor(x, y, w, h, img, weight, descr) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.img = img;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.descr = descr;

  }

  show() {
    //draws from the center of the image
    imageMode(CENTER);
    image(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);  
    //image(this.img, this.x, this.h, this.w, this.h);
    //console.log("(100*(this.weight/originalTargetWeight)) = " + (100*(this.weight/originalTargetWeight)))

  }

  moveDown() {
    this.y = this.y - 2;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry about that! I just added the JSON in-line. The code still looks for images in /images, but hopefully this is enough to be able to get a sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

It was, in fact, an obvious thing. Turns out that I needed to divide the objectRadius in half in order to keep the images out of the middle of the canvas.

This line:

```
itemObject = new Block(width / 2, objectRadius, objectRadius, objectRadius, objectImage, parseFloat(objectWeight), objectDescription);
```

becomes:

```
itemObject = new Block(width / 2, objectRadius/2, objectRadius, objectRadius, objectImage, parseFloat(objectWeight), objectDescription);
```